# Is it advisable to restart informatica application monthly to improve performance?

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence, informatica, informatica-powercenter

We have around 32 datamarts loading around 200+ tables out of which 50% of tables are on 11g Oracle database and 30% on 10g and rest 20 are flat files. 
Lately we are facing performance issues while loading the datamarts.

Database parameters as well are network parameters are looking and as throughput is decreasing drastically we are of the opinion now that it is informatica which has problem.

Recently when through put had gone down and server was utilized to its 90% informatica application was restarted and the performance there after was little better than previous performance.

So my question is should we have Informatica restart as a scheduled activity ? Does restart actually improves the performance of the application or there are some other things which can play a role in the same?

Comment: Can not say for sure, but the practice shows it's something normal to have maintenance every third month at least. This maintance everytime includes restart of Informatica.

Comment: can you provide me link to best practices for informatica or any documented information

Comment: No. What I've seen so far is always proprietary and decided by the IPC admins.

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is a systemic problem, but you have not established which component(s) of the system are the cause.

Are all jobs showing exactly the same degradation in performance? If not, what is the common characteristic of those that are? Not all jobs will have the same reliance on the Informatica server -- some will be dependent more on the performance of their target system(s), some on their source system(s), so I would be amazed if all showed exactly the same level of degradation.

What you have here is an exercise in data gathering, and then turning that data into useful information.

If you can isolate the problem to only certain jobs then I would take a log file from a time when the system is performing well, and from a time when it is not, and compare them directly, looking for differences in the performance of their components. You can also look at any database monitoring tools for changes in execution plan.

Rebooting servers? Maybe, but that is not necessarily the solution -- the real problem is the lack of data you have to diagnose your system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is good to do a restart every quarter.
It will refresh the Integration service cache.
Delete files from Cache and storage before you restart.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you have recently seen some reduced performance recently it might be due various reasons.

Some tips that may help:

1. Ensure all `Indexes` are in `valid` and `compiled` state.
2. If you are calling a `procedure` via worflow check the `EXPLAIN` plan and `Cost` ensure it is not doing a full table scan(cost should be less).

3.`Gather stats` on the source or target tables  (especially which have `deletes` )) - This will help in `de fragmentation` - deleting the un allocated space. [DBMS_STATS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/stats.htm)

4. Always good to have an `house keeping` scheduled weekly to do the above checks on `indexes`,remove temp/unnecessary files and `gather stats` (analyze indexes and tables).

Some best practices here [performance tips](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/toc.htm)